# java design - user preset system

Tags: java

I'm working on a pattern system where the user can store presets of all the parameters, and I want to include the possibility to interpolate between presets. We are talking about many parameters (80-100), so I guess it has to be as fast as possible. What would be a smart way to do this?
Some useful suggestions are very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might store them in a properties file, either in the users home directory or by including the user name in the file name.

If you have access to a database you could also store the presets there.

As for the interpolation, that depends on what values you have to interpolate between. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Hi Thomas. There are diferent kind of fields, floats, ints, and floats[], ints[].. Would you suggest XML? Thanks!

Comment: @menemenemu In case of arrays, yes you could use xml. Alternatively store the arrays as comma separated lists, e.g. `somearray=1,2,3,4`. That would be equally readable in case of primitive arrays (complex objects should better be expressed using some more complext markup, e.g. JSON) and parsing such a string might be faster than parsing xml (not that those minimal differences would matter :) ).

Comment: Thanks for the hints Thomas! I will start with JSON.